# Nested Loops In Oracle Not Work Correctly (Exceeds the maximum)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I wrote These Two queries For Sample Table to insert into "z_exp14_resualt" From "z_exp14_main ". The **First Query Works Correctly** (Null) But Second That  For rows have due_date on the main table (Not Null), not works correctly! . I Think Problem is The loop.
 **It started before the due date and even goes beyond that** . For NOT Nulls Insert must start from today(year and monts from sysdate and day from opening_date) and continue until due_date

**Calculate For Null DUE_DATES**

```
declare
  i number := 1;
BEGIN
for i in 1..12 loop
  insert into z_exp14_resualt 
  select dep_id,ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(opening_date,trunc( months_between (sysdate,opening_date))),i),rate*balance 
  from z_exp14_main
  WHERE due_date IS  null;
end loop;
END;
/
```

**And For Not Null Due_dates**

```
  DECLARE
    diff number;
    x number :=1;
    BEGIN    
    for i in (select * FROM z_exp14_main WHERE due_date IS NOT null) loop    
        diff :=trunc( months_between (sysdate,i.opening_date));
        
            WHILE (ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(i.opening_date,diff),x)<i.due_date) LOOP
                insert into z_exp14_resualt 
                select dep_id,ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(i.opening_date,diff),x),rate*balance 
                from z_exp14_main WHERE due_date is not null  ;
                x :=x+1;
            end loop;
      end loop;
    end;
    /
```

sample Date On Main (z_exp14_main)

| -- | DEP_ID | DUE_DATE | BALANCE | RATE | OPENING_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -- | 20056634 | null | 283428 | 10 | 15-SEP-16 |
| -- | 20056637 | null | 180222 | 10 | 07-NOV-14 |
| -- | 20056639 | null | 58741 | 10 | 28-AUG-14 |
| -- | 40000020 | 27-NOV-21 | 5000000 | 22 | 31-MAR-14 |
| -- | 40000023 | 23-APR-21 | 63000000 | 22 | 25-AUG-18 |

Comment: have you tried something so far ? stackoverflow.com is not a free coding service. We can help, but you should try first by yourself and come back to us with your doubts or problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question, is a request for free coding service

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I Edit The Question and Add My Queries. The First One Is Works and The Second Have Problem In loop ... Thank you for your reminder

Comment: Please describe what you are attempting in non-SQL terms. Also what  is the goal of the date formula: `(ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(i.opening_date,diff),x)`. Finally, your data does not include the column `opening_date` but that seems to be the central column in the procedure. Please include it.

Comment: @Belayer The purpose of calculating the deposit interest is the date and number of deposits for each ID. For example, I opened an account on 28-MAR-14 and the final deadline is 30-NOV-21. Maturity calculation will be as follows. The day is taken from the date opening and the month and year from sysdate, and for each month a record goes to due date: 28-OCT-21, 28-SEP-21, 28-NOV-21

Comment: @Belayer in DIFF I Calculate The Months between the opening_date and today. So When Add The DIFF To the Opening_Date, First DUE_DATE Clears. THe Day Of Due_Date Is Important. Because Is me Opened My Account 14th day of Monts, My Due_date will Be 14th Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem Is In the "While" condition. I correct it And This Is Final Answer:

```
DECLARE
    diff number;
    x number ;
    BEGIN    
    for i in (select * FROM z_exp14_main WHERE due_date IS NOT null) loop    
        diff :=trunc( months_between (sysdate,i.opening_date));
        x:=0;
            WHILE (add_months(sysdate,x)<i.due_date) LOOP
                insert into z_exp14_resualt values (i.dep_id,ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(i.opening_date,diff),x),(i.rate*i.balance) );
                x :=x+1;
            end loop;
      end loop;
    end;
    /
```